# plt.plot() function does not plot the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'total':[total], 'success_count':[success_count], 'fail_count':[fail_count]})
plt.plot(df)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Grant Summary')
plt.show()
```

I am able to print df successfully but `plt.plot(df)` is returning a grid without the plot. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you mean `df.plot()`?

Comment: The code itself might or might not work, depending on what `df` is (i.e. what `total`, `success_count`, ... are). Are they single numbers? In that case, a single point cannot be shown as a line. Are they lists? In that case matplotlib would not know how to plot a list of lists.

Comment: Here is the code df = pd.DataFrame({'total':[total], 'success_count':[success_count], 'fail_count':[fail_count]}) Output :                                            total  success_count  fail_count
   11            11                0                                                                                              df.plot() displays only the legends but there is no plot for the values for total and success_count.